# React : how to prevent the hidden component from appearing during rendering?

Tags: reactjs, render

During rendering of the part below, the component CreateGarden appears for 1 sec even if the condition is true.

```
  {userInfo.gardenName ?
    <ShowPlants />
    :
    <CreateGarden setModal={setModal} />
  }
```

Here is the custom hook I use to get userInfo

```
export default function useUserInfo() {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([]);
    const [categories, setCategories]= useState([]);

    const userRef = doc(allUsers,auth.currentUser.uid);

    useEffect(() => {  
       const unsub = onSnapshot(userRef, (doc)=>{
         setUserInfo(doc.data())
         setCategories(doc.data().categories)
         }) 

         return ()=>unsub()
      },[auth.currentUser]);

    return {userInfo, categories};
}
```

I tried creating loading state in the hook and use it as additional condition to render but it's  still the same , I keep having a glimpse of the hidden component.

EDIT//SOLUTION:
Finally, after different versions I used the following solution

```
export default function useUserInfo() {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
    const [categories, setCategories]= useState([]);

    const userRef = doc(allUsers,auth.currentUser.uid);

    useEffect(() => {  
       const unsub = onSnapshot(userRef, (doc)=>{
         setUserInfo(doc.data())
         setCategories(doc.data().categories)
         }) 
         setLoading(false)
       
         return ()=>unsub()
      },[auth.currentUser]);
  
    return {userInfo, categories, loading};
}
```

In the component:

```
      {userInfo.gardenName && <ShowPlants />}

      {!userInfo.gardenName && !loading && <CreateGarden setModal={setModal} />}
```

Comment: Set gardenName to false (or whatever it needs to be) in the class state definition, please also include the component in question in your question

Comment: You are inserting element in `userInfo` with `useEffect` so before it's an empty array hence `<CreateGarden/>` is visible for few second until `userInfo` becomes `Truthy Value`. You can set `userInfo` to `true` or `false` as required at initial condition.

Comment: "even if the condition is true" That's not possible. When this happens, userInfo.gardenName must be a falsy value.

Comment: Also, is userInfo an object or an array? If it's an object, then why is it set to an empty array by default?.

Comment: gardenName initially does not exist, it's created in firestore with CreateGarden component, once it's created the component is not needed anymore.  (The component it's too big to be readable so I decided no to include. It's a form taking the name of a garden and its categories ). I tried making initial state of userInfo false it does not make any difference. UserInfo is in fact object, but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could display a loading icon while the data is being fetched.

When

1. data hasn't been fetched yet (undefined) -> show loading icon (your hook could return a loading value as well as an error value in case something went wrong)
2. data has been fetched and there is a gardenName, display ShowPlants
3. data has been fetched and there is no gardenName, display CreateGarden

Comment: It was my first idea , I tried creating loading state . I am not using the loading icon but I wanted to use it as a condition.           {userInfo.gardenName && !loading ? 
            <ShowPlants />
            :
            <CreateGarden setModal={setModal} />
          }

Comment: This won't work. You don't want to display any of these components if userInfo hasn't been fetched. So you have to return something else in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately even with the loader  it does not work. It tried  and I have the glimpse of component just before the loader . I really don't see why

Comment: It's not possible. You're doing something wrong. You have to show me the code so that I can help you further.

Comment: I just added my code to the question.  I thought maybe the problem is in the component CreateGarden but even if I replace it with another it's the same...

Comment: setLoading should be in onSnapshot.

Answer (score -2):

What if you use them separately?

```
{ userInfo.gardenName && <ShowPlants /> }

{ !userInfo.gardenName && <CreateGarden setModal={setModal} /> }
```

Comment: tried it too, it does not work